# How to select only tapped cells with button?

Tags: swift, tableview

Good time of day, in my app i have a tableview and custom cell, in cell there are labels, button and progressBar, so that when i tap button download proceeds and progressBar shows progress, but when i scroll down i realise that there are other cells are selected and shows progress and when i scroll up again progress of my selected cell stops. Could you help, any feedbacks appreciated )

That's my TableViewController :

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return titles.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        cell.pesnya.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        cell.pevets.text = artists[indexPath.row]
        cell.url = urls[indexPath.row]
    return (cell)
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    (sender as! UIButton).isSelected = !(sender as! UIButton).isSelected
    if (sender as! UIButton).isSelected {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender.superview!?.superview as! UITableViewCell) {
            DownloadManager.shared.download(url: urls[indexPath.row], title: titles[indexPath.row])
        }
    } else {
        //            (sender as! UIButton).setTitle("Удалить", for: UIControlState.normal)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender.superview!?.superview as! UITableViewCell) {
            let name = "\(titles[indexPath.row]).mp3"
            let name2 = name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
            let filePathURL = URL(string:"string")
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePathURL!)
            } catch {
                print("Could not delete file: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to save your button state in datasource.

Answer (score 0):

This is because table view cell will be reused when you scroll. Set views to initial status in cell's `prepareForReuse`. Like this:

```
class ACell: UITableViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        view.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer almost helped, but when i set here button like isSelected = false, my selected button also becomes not selected that wrong for me, what do you think?

Comment: @Oklahoma You should recover status in table view data source, mostly in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: Proper way to use `UITableView` is to manage the data internally, so all selections should be stored in your data model, not as button properties.

Comment: @Oklahoma As Legoless said, you should save status in your models first.

Comment: @Lumialxk how to recover, could you give example pls?

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int
{
return titles.count
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
 indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: 
 indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
cell.pesnya.text = titles[indexPath.row]
 cell.pevets.text = artists[indexPath.row]
cell.url = urls[indexPath.row]
// Create IBOutlet for button
cell.btnPressed.tag = indexPath.row
cell.btnPressed.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

if  cell.btnPressed.isSelected {
    DownloadManager.shared.download(url: urls[indexPath.row], title: titles[indexPath.row])
}else {
    let name = "\(titles[indexPath.row]).mp3"
    let name2 = name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    let filePathURL = URL(string:"string")
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePathURL!)
    } catch {
        print("Could not delete file: \(error)")
    }

}

return (cell)
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
let indexPath =  IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? 
  ViewControllerTableViewCell {
    cell.btnPressed.isSelected = !cell.btnPressed.isSelected
     tableview.reloadData()
  }

}
```